# Limit camera rotation angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to able to restrict camera rotation after a certain point and only be able to rotate in a certain area, this is the code so far...

```
void Update() {
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float mouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    rotY += mouseX * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    rotX += mouseY * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    desiredy = Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y;
    desiredx = Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.x;

    if (!(desiredy < maxy && desiredy > miny))
    {
        //i dont know what to put in here, i have tried everything
    }


    else if (!(desiredx < maxx && desiredx > minx))
    {
         //i dont know what to put in here, i have tried everything
    }

    else
    {
        localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0.0f);
        transform.rotation = localRotation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making this complicated with your unnecessary logic. All you need is the `Mathf.Clamp` function that makes sure that your value is within specified range.

```
void Update()
{
    rotateCamera();
}


public float xSensitivity = 100.0f;
public float ySensitivity = 100.0f;

public float yMinLimit = -45.0f;
public float yMaxLimit = 45.0f;

public float xMinLimit = -360.0f;
public float xMaxLimit = 360.0f;

float yRot = 0.0f;
float xRot = 0.0f;

void rotateCamera()
{
    xRot += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    yRot += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    yRot = Mathf.Clamp(yRot, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
    Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-yRot, xRot, 0);

}
```

Comment: wierd i tried that before didnt work now its working... btw thanks

Comment: @onion123 Probably because you were using `transform.rotation` instead of `transform.localEulerAngles`